# I am trying to run a mailing form in php. This is the HTML with Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, contact-form

I am doing a contact page for a site that uses framework Twitter Bootstrap 3.0. This is the HTML.

```
<form action="mail.php" name="contactform"  method="post" id="contact-form">
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name"> Name</label>

                                    <input id="name" class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter you name" value="" required/>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                 <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                                <div id="input_email" class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
                                    <input id="email" class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" value="" required />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="subject"> Subject</label>

                                    <input id="subject" class="form-control" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject"/>

                            </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div id="input_message" class="col-md-12">
                                    <textarea id="comments" class="form-control" name="message" rows="6" placeholder="Your Suggestion ..." value="" required ></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                <!-- Submit Button -->
                                <div class="col-md-12">

                                    <input class="btn btn-skin pull-right" type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            </form>
```

This is the PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content=" Contact Form Validation.">
<meta name="author" content="Julian Vanegas">
    <title>Mailing</title>
     <!--Favicon-->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<!-- Bridge -->
<link href="bridge-contactphp.css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-custom">
<!-- Preloader -->
<div id="preloader">
  <div id="load"></div>
</div>

  <!--Navbar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top top-nav-collapse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">
                <img  src="img/logo-svg.svg"class="logo"></img>
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html#services">Services</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="sitemap.html">Sitemap</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown">More<b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Globalnode Acad</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

    <?php
        $form_htmlString = "";
        if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['subject']) || empty($_POST['message'])){
            $form_htmlString = <<<EOD
            <section id=\"intro\" class=\"intro\"><div class=\"gallery-intro\"><h2> <span class=\"text_color\"> <span>fadfasfads</span> </h2><h4></h4></div><div class=\"page-scroll\"><a href=\"#sitemap\" class=\"btn btn-circle\"><i class=\"fa fa-angle-double-down animated\"></i></a></div></section><div class=\"container\"> <div class=\"row\"> <div class=\"col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center padding-20\"><div class=\"wow bounceInUp\" data-wow-delay=\"0.2s\"> <div class=\"team boxed-grey\"> <div class=\"inner\"><h5 alt=\"Internal-link List\">  Check the information you typed in. </h5> <p class=\"subtitle\"> There is one or more mistakes. </p></div></div></div></div></div></div>
            EOD;    
        }else{
            $sendTo = "jumisingo@hotmail.es";
            $subject ="Mensaje de contacto";
            $title  = "Alguien se ha contactado con usted";
            $name = $_POST["name"];
            $email = $_POST["email"];
            $subject = $_POST["subject"];
            $comments = $_POST["message"];
            $message = "\nAlguien se ha contactado con usted:"."\nNombre: ".$name."\nEmail: ".$email."\nAsunto: ".$subject."\nComentarios: ".$comments;
            mail($sendTo, $subject, $message);      
            $form_htmlString = "<section id=\"intro\" class=\"intro\"><div class=\"gallery-intro\"><h2> <span class=\"text_color\"> <span>fadfasfads</span> </h2><h4></h4></div><div class=\"page-scroll\"><a href=\"#sitemap\" class=\"btn btn-circle\"><i class=\"fa fa-angle-double-down animated\"></i></a></div></section><div class=\"container\"> <div class=\"row\"> <div class=\"col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center padding-20\"><div class=\"wow bounceInUp\" data-wow-delay=\"0.2s\"> <div class=\"team boxed-grey\"> <div class=\"inner\"><h5 alt=\"Internal-link List\">  Check the information you typed in. </h5> <p class=\"subtitle\"> There is one or more mistakes. </p></div></div></div></div></div></div>";
            echo $form_htmlString;
        }
    ?>

    <footer id="sitemap"><div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12"><div class="wow shake" data-wow-delay="0.4s"><div class="page-scroll marginbot-30 pull-right"><a href="#intro" id="totop" class="btn btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-up animated"></i></a></div></div><p>&copy;Copyright 2015 - Global Node Inc. All rights reserved.</p></div></div></div></footer>

  </body>
```

When I run the if, it should evaluate the data entered in the HTML through the ifs, and echo the html depending on the break, yet it echoes part of the php too. I have searched for solutions and I saw heredoc works, but in this case it didn't. Any clue?

Comment: *"yet it echoes part of the php too"* - Um... is your file `.php` or not? Running local or hosted? Is PHP installed? So many questions. You'll need to elaborate on that; echos what part?

Comment: it is php, I need $form_htmlString to have some html code dependind on result of the if.

Comment: if you get php code, then something's shutting off php, or it's not being executed at all. do a `view source`. if you see `<?php`, then something's screwed up on your server, and the php code is being mis-rendered as an unknown html tag.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. Make sure that PHP is installed, running and properly configured. I tested it; no problems. So, the issue is on your end. How are you running this; on your own computer or a hosted site?

Comment: This is what the server replies."
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /home2/ina2015/public_html/gna/contact.php on line 76

Comment: This is the 76th line:
$name = $_POST["name"];

Comment: What you posted for code, will **not** cause that error. Post your full and actual code. Plus, the error isn't on line 76, but the one or another **above** that.

Comment: @fred-ii

You can take a look on the main question box. By the way thank your for your help, I'm really frustrated atm.

Comment: The site is http://gna.ina-fe-2015.com/contact.html

Comment: I found the problem and have posted an answer for you below.

Comment: I posted my answer 25 mins. prior to this comment; have you removed the spaces before and after `EOD;`? It's outlined in my answer and have you tried it? No word from you since I posted my comment/answer.

Comment: Yes @fred-ii thank you. Sorry for no answering I lost internet connection until now. Therefore I could load the answer you posted. I modified the old code and removed the spaces, I am now uploading. I'll keep you udated with result. Once again, thank you.

Comment: @JumisingoVanegasDiaz Ah ok. Well if my answer works which am confident it will, you could mark it as correct by accepting the answer so others will also see that it has been solved. *Cheers*

Comment: @fred-ii it works, thank you so much bro, I'm a php fan, since its pretty useful for web functions and stuff, nevertheless I had never used  for real work purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"This is what the server replies." Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /home2/ina2015/public_html/gna/contact.php on line 76"*

The error is in this block of code for your heredoc.

```
<?php
    $form_htmlString = "";
    if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['subject']) || empty($_POST['message'])){
        $form_htmlString = <<<EOD
        <section id=\"intro\" class=\"intro\"><div class=\"gallery-intro\"><h2> <span class=\"text_color\"> <span>fadfasfads</span> </h2><h4></h4></div><div class=\"page-scroll\"><a href=\"#sitemap\" class=\"btn btn-circle\"><i class=\"fa fa-angle-double-down animated\"></i></a></div></section><div class=\"container\"> <div class=\"row\"> <div class=\"col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center padding-20\"><div class=\"wow bounceInUp\" data-wow-delay=\"0.2s\"> <div class=\"team boxed-grey\"> <div class=\"inner\"><h5 alt=\"Internal-link List\">  Check the information you typed in. </h5> <p class=\"subtitle\"> There is one or more mistakes. </p></div></div></div></div></div></div>
        EOD;  
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ It contains spaces. There should not be any.
```

There should not be anything before or after your closing identifier.

Modify it to be as: (no spaces before or after `EOD;`)

```
<?php
    $form_htmlString = "";
    if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['subject']) || empty($_POST['message'])){
        $form_htmlString = <<<EOD
        <section id=\"intro\" class=\"intro\"><div class=\"gallery-intro\"><h2> <span class=\"text_color\"> <span>fadfasfads</span> </h2><h4></h4></div><div class=\"page-scroll\"><a href=\"#sitemap\" class=\"btn btn-circle\"><i class=\"fa fa-angle-double-down animated\"></i></a></div></section><div class=\"container\"> <div class=\"row\"> <div class=\"col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center padding-20\"><div class=\"wow bounceInUp\" data-wow-delay=\"0.2s\"> <div class=\"team boxed-grey\"> <div class=\"inner\"><h5 alt=\"Internal-link List\">  Check the information you typed in. </h5> <p class=\"subtitle\"> There is one or more mistakes. </p></div></div></div></div></div></div>
EOD;
```

- https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

From the manual:

> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon. It's also important to realize that the first character before the closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system. This is \n on UNIX systems, including Mac OS X. The closing delimiter must also be followed by a newline.